# How do I expand stack base on the position widget

Tags: flutter, position

I have a message card, the message has properties like message time, etc.
the message is positioned with a **Stack** widget.
The message data (time etc.) is in the **Positioned** widget.

#### The problem is:

The message card is expanded based on the message text, but not based on the message data (time etc.)

How do I expand the card based on the position also?

```
 Align(
        alignment: isMe ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 45,
          ),
          child: Card(
            elevation: 1,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: typeOfMessage == MessageEnum.text
                      ? const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 10,
                          right: 30,
                          top: 5,
                          bottom: 20,
                        )
                      : const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 5,
                          top: 5,
                          right: 5,
                          bottom: 25,
                        ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
                    child: Text(
                      message,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 4,
                  right: 10,
                  left: 10,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          sendWith,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13,
                            color: Color.fromARGB(153, 5, 5, 5),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 5),
                      Text(
                        formatTimeToLocal(time),
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 13,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(153, 9, 8, 8),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: you will try Expanded widget instead of Flexible widget.

Comment: i tried it's not work

Comment: look into this code snippet https://github.com/saiful2396/single_chat/blob/main/lib/view/conversation_screen.dart

Comment: it return 404 is it a public repo?

Comment: sorry it was in a private repo, Now it's public try again please